# How does d3.js decides how many and which ticks to show?

Tags: svg, d3.js, zooming

On my chart, I have a time scale xAxis. I want user can do zoom in, zoom out operations to switch among month view(display ticks of one month), week view( display ticks of a week, Mon, Tue, Wed ...), day view( display ticks of 24 hours).

When I call the zoom behavior on svg. My chart is stretching and condensing nicely. But the ticks on the xAxis are changing "gradually" which is not what I want. E.g. when I zoom in at a certain scale, the ticks are [May 3, May 5, May 7 ......], the ticks D3 decides randomly seem to be skipping one day. And it will happen when user zoom further into hours as well.

What I want is: Assume that user is initially on the month view(which displays ticks of one month), then user keeps zooming in till to a certain scale, the ticks of xAxis will turn into 7 days( Mon, Tue, Wed ...... ), if user keeps zooming in, at a certain scale, the ticks turn into hours. I don't want d3 to decide ticks randomly.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: The only way to set exactly what you want is to pass that explicitly to `.tickValues()`.

Answer (score 1):

For each zoom scale you should set `axis.ticks()` and `axis.tickFormat()` explicitly.
When zoom event occurs you can call something like this:

```
adjustTimeAxis: function() {
    switch(this.getZoomState()) {
        case 'longDays':
            this.axis
                .ticks(d3.time.days, 1)
                .tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.time.format('%a %e')(d); })
                .tickSubdivide(false);
            break;
        case 'shortDays':
            this.axis
                .ticks(d3.time.days, 1)
                .tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.time.format('%e')(d); })
                .tickSubdivide(false);
            break;
        case 'weeks':
            this.axis
                .ticks(d3.time.mondays, 1)
                .tickFormat(null)
                .tickSubdivide(6);
            break;
        default: // months
            this.axis
                .ticks(d3.time.months, 1)
                .tickFormat(null)
                .tickSubdivide(1);
    }
} // adjustTimeAxis
```

In this code function `this.getZoomState` returns one of the string values `['longDays', 'shortDays', 'weeks']` depending on zoom scale.
You can see how this code works here: http://bl.ocks.org/oluckyman/6199145